# React exporting useContext causes errors

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Context.js

```
const GlobalContext = React.createContext();

const initState = {count:0};

const GlobalContextProvider = props => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initState);

    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={{state:state, setState:setState}}>
            {props.children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
};

const GlobalContextValue = useContext(GlobalContext)

export {GlobalContextValue, GlobalContextProvider}
```

When I exported the GlobalContextValue, Chrome or React throws an error saying this is an invalid hook call, but I want to be able use setState in a module that's showing below.

fetchAPI.js

```
import { GlobalContextValue } from './GlobalContext';

const {state, setState} = GlobalContextValue;

function load() {
    fetch('localhost:8000/load')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => setState(json));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use hooks outside of React functional components.

You can probably do this another way though.

**Disclaimer:** I didn't test this code, but it should do what you want, although I don't recommend doing this at all.

```
const GlobalContext = React.createContext();

const globalState = { count: 0 }
let subscribers = []

export function setGlobalState(value) {
  Object.assign(globalState, value)
  subscribers.forEach(f => f(globalState))
}

export function subscribe(handler) {
  subscribers.push(handler)
  return () => {
    subscribers = subscribers.filter(s => s !== handler)
  }
}

const GlobalContextProvider = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(globalState)
  useEffect(() => subscribe(setState), [])

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ state: state, setState: setGlobalState }}>
        {props.children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```